# Webservice response message can't be handled in Ksoap2 of android

Tags: android, web-services, list, android-ksoap2

I have a webservice method which returns value in list as a response for my application.In key value pairs <"item","http://www.codegeeks.com/">.
When I get this response at my application end,it shows me problem related to casting of soapobject to list.
My simple code to get response is :-

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);  

            // request.addProperty("MENU", "Menu");               
            // request.addProperty("Pass",Password);             

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Please help me to change this soapobject value to list.I am in big trouble due to it.Help please.

Comment: post the stack trace.